# Using Python I can't send email using gmail smtp server from within my Corporate LAN. Why

Tags: python, email, server, smtp, send

I have searched many python email related post here but I seem not able to send a single email using python. I am working within corporate LAN. But If I use my company's smtp relay server I am able to send email to gmail, or my company ID or other emails.This is very strange or it is suppose to be this way? How can I use gmail smtp server to send email outside?

Here are few scripts I have tried.
====================================1==

```
import smtplib

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login("xyz@gmail.com", "myPasswd")

msg = "YOUR MESSAGE!"
server.sendmail("xyz@gmail.com", "xyz@gmail.com", msg)
server.quit()
```

===================================2==

```
import smtplib
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = 'sender@gmail.com'
msg['To'] = 'recvr@gmail.com'
msg['Subject'] = 'simple email in python'
message = 'here is the email'
msg.attach(MIMEText(message))

mailserver = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
# identify ourselves to smtp gmail client
mailserver.ehlo()
# secure our email with tls encryption
mailserver.starttls()
# re-identify ourselves as an encrypted connection
mailserver.ehlo()
mailserver.login('sender@gmail.com', 'pswd')

mailserver.sendmail('sender@gmail.com','rcvr@gmail.com',msg.as_string())

mailserver.quit()
```

======================================

I am sure it is nothing to do with code but something else I am missing.

Comment: "not able to send" -> What errors do you get? What is the problem you're running into?

Comment: Using above python script nothing is happening means no error message. It just stays, no output. So after few minutes I check if email is sent -nothing. I have to stop run-time manually.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem

It seems that google find your application is insecure. You can:

- Allow less secure applications to connect to the server in google apps settings. see [Allowing less secure apps to access your account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en)
- Secure your code [whatever it means by google ...]

Comment: I have tried this after enabling less secured option. Seems like not working it either.